# R: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, regression

I am running a regression with one categorical predictor (`Group`), one categorical covariate (`Sex`), and two continuous covariates on R. Once I use the `model.check` function, this error comes up:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I have looked at a lot of the discussion boards here, and I have reviewed my data countless times. My `Group` and `Sex` variables are entered as factors with three and two levels, respectively. I checked for missing data, I checked to see if there were any errors in group names, but nothing. I am not sure what to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE! Your question is about errors in a code. These type of questions are off-topic in this site. Please see our help page for more information. In general when asking the software related questions it is very advisable to give a reproducible example.

Comment: What is the `model.check` function?